# What is the full function of TCPIP_TCP_ArrayGet of Harmony Configurator?

Tags: c, microchip

I read the docs of TCPIP module of Harmony Configurator however it's lacking of documentation and I just wanna know if someone knows about the complete/detailed functionality of TCPIP_TCP_ArrayGet function. Please help me out and be kind to me cause I'm just a newbie here on stackoverflow and on the project I'm working on. Thanks

DOCUMENTATION 
TCPIP_TCP_ArrayGet
Reads an array of data bytes from a TCP socket's RX buffer/FIFO. The data is removed from the FIFO in the process.

uint16_t TCPIP_TCP_ArrayGet(
    TCP_SOCKET htcp,
    uint8_t* buffer,
    uint16_t* count
);

Precondition
TCP is initialized

Parameters
htcp   - the socket from which data is to be read.
buffer - pointer to the array to store data that was read.
len    - number of bytes to be read.

Returns 
    The number of bytes read from the socket. If less than len, the RX FIFO buffer became empty or the socket is not connected.

THANKS FOR THE HELP.

Comment: Why not ask this at microchip?

Comment: I already did. No one has responded yet  but stackoverflow users might help me too about this.

Comment: However, that is not a totorial site - please understand. If you have any specific question about details, please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Nice reference. Thanks

Comment: I have some knowledge of the microchip TCP/IP stack (on dspic though), but I don't understand what you mean. You want more information but do not specify what kind of information you expect